# using HTTParty to test api response times

Tags: ruby, api, testing, automation, httparty

We have some performance enhancements coming to one of our api services. I was asked to get some random data and log the response times for the new and old so we can see side by side examples. I wrote a quick script to grab random data from the db and iterate through that result set using the same data in both calls. I am making both calls with httparty in the same loop but it seems like the first call is way slower than it should be. If I switch the two around the old call is now faster and it shouldn't be. Below is what im doing.

If I switch around the old and new call, I should see the time reflected but it doesn't and the new call is now really slow.

Can anybody shine some light on what Im doing wrong? Thanks ahead of time. (Let me know if my problem is unclear)

```
class ProductCompare < Test::Unit::TestCase

def test_compare

 def time_diff(start, finish)
   ((finish - start) * 1000.0).to_i
 end

 begin
   api_conn = Mysql.new()

   random_skus = api_conn.query("Select random data")

   random_skus.each do |row|

     puts row.join("\s")

         products1 = "http://api-call-old/#{row.join("\s")}"
         start_time1 = Time.now
         response1 = HTTParty.get(products1)
         end_time1 = Time.now
         products1_elapsed_tm = time_diff(start_time1, end_time1)

     puts "The response time for response1 is: #{products1_elapsed_tm} ms"

         products2 = "http://api-call-new/#{row.join("\s")}"
         start_time2 = Time.now
         response2 = HTTParty.get(products2)
         end_time2 = Time.now
         products2_elapsed_tm = time_diff(start_time2, end_time2)

     puts "The response time for response2 is: #{products2_elapsed_tm} ms"

     assert_equal(response1.body, response2.body, 'The products responce did not match')
   end

    api_conn.close
 rescue Mysql::Error => e
    puts e.error
 ensure
    api_conn.close if api_conn
 end
 end
end
```

Comment: It's possible that something like the DNS resolution is slowing down the first call no matter which it is. If you make a dummy first request to 'prime the pump' so to speak, do the real ones perform right after that?

Comment: Yes, instead of using a FQDN in your URL, use the IP address of the host. That should help remove any DNS uncertainty from things. Also, consider using cURL for your testing. It's great for automating a test like you're doing, and by using `time curl …` you'll get elapsed time for the test.

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools, I added the "priming" call before my logged one and that seems to help, they are now responding normally. Is there a better way to write a test like this?